# A simple criterion for semi-simplicity

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I made a simple observation about semi-simplicity of rings:

> A ring $R$ is semi-simple iff for  every $x\in R$ there is an element $y\in R$ s.t. $xyx=x$.

It seems very interesting to have such a simple criterion for semi-simplicity. It should be known but I couldn't find a reference. Does there exists good references and other analogs?

**Edit.** As mentioned by Dietrich-Burde in the answers the above criterion is wrong. But one can prove that if all of endomorphism rings in an abelian category are Von Neumann  regular then every object is semisimple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such rings are called [*von Neumann regular rings*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_regular_ring). Every semisimple ring is von Neumann regular, but conversely not every von Neumann regular ring is semisimple. This is true, though, if we assume left (or right) Noetherian in addition.

Comment: Thanks! I found the mistake. The above criterion is equivalent to the condition that every principal left (or right) ideal is a factor in a direct sum. So you are right.